# Perl parsing - mixture of chars, tabs and spaces

Tags: perl, parsing

I have the following types of line in my code:

```
MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS = 1,        /*clock outputs system*/
MMAPI_SYSTEM_MANAGEMENT = 0,    /*sys man system*/
```

I want to parse them to get:

```
'MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS' 
'1'
'clock outputs system'
```

So I tried:

```
elsif($TheLine =~ /\s*(.*)s*=s*(.*),s*\/*(.*)*\//)
```

but this doesn't get the last string 'clock outputs system'
What should the parsing code actually be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex: `/^\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(\d+),\s*\/\*(.*?)\*\/$/`

Here is an example in which you can test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS = 1,        /*clock outputs system*/\n
           MMAPI_SYSTEM_MANAGEMENT = 0,    /*sys man system*/";

while ($str =~ /^\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(\d+),\s*\/\*(.*?)\*\/$/gm) {
    print "$1 $2 $3 \n";
}

# Output:
# MMAPI_CLOCK_OUTPUTS 1 clock outputs system
# MMAPI_SYSTEM_MANAGEMENT 0 sys man system
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the slashes, stars and the `s` for spaces. Instead of writing `/`, `*` or `s` in your regex, write `\/`, `\*` and `\s`:

```
/\s*(.*)\s=\s*(.*),\s\/\*(.*)\*\//
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but that didnt work either. I still dont get the last string within /*...*/

Comment: still gets $1 and $2 but not $3

Answer (score 1):

```
if($TheLine =~ m%^(\S+)\s+=\s+(\d+),\s+/\*(.*)\*/%) {
    print "$1 $2 $3\n"
}
```

This uses `%` as an alternative delimiter in order to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) when you escape the `/` characters.

Comment: also still gets $1 and $2 but not $3